# Calling a function recursively in the context of "export default"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, es6-modules

This may be obvious to others but I don't know the syntax for calling a function recursively in the following code:

```
//request.js
    export default {

      send() {
       ... do stuff ...
       this.send(); // Can't call "send" of undefined
      }
    }

//main.js
import request from './request'

export default class Main extends Component {
   init() {
      request.send();
  }
}
```

In the above example, I'm calling the send function from main.js. All this is working fine but I have a condition in the send function that will recall the same function. The problem is that I have no idea how to call the function from within the function. Anybody?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide more information, and possibly more of your code? Also, the syntax `send(....)` does not look valid, since the contents of the parenthesis must be a parameter list, and your sample appears to have arbitrary javascript code in the parameter list.

Comment: @mangotang Yeah sorry, the syntax wasn't correct. I made some edits to better illustrate my issue.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to write: `const send = function() { }; export default { send };` ?

Comment: @user3297291- No reason but still curious as to how someone would handle this situation

Comment: I cannot see any reason why this code would not work (other than a possible infinite loop). At what point is the `Can't call "send" of undefined` message being generated? There must be something else to this that you aren't showing us.

Comment: For ES6 this is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call the default export recursively in Node.js, using Babel.js to transpile, you can use the exports object:

```
// request.js

export default {
  send() {
    console.log('Yo');
    setTimeout(() => {
      exports.default.send();
    }, 1000);
  },
};
```

Importing:

```
// main.js

import request from './request';

request.send(); // Writes "Yo" to the console once per second
```

This is because Babel.js simply transforms to the CommonJS syntax. This:

```
export default 42;
```

Becomes this:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

exports.default = 42;
```

No idea how this may change in a future implementation of ES6 Modules in Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why `this.send()` wouldn't work, given you are exporting an object with a method.

But if it doesn't work, you can always use a named function expression:

```
export default {
  send: function send() {
    … send() …
  }
};
```

or a named function declaration:

```
function send() {
  … send() …
}
export default { send };
```

or just name your exported object:

```
export default const request = {
  send() {
    … request.send() …
  }
};
```

But I would recommend to not default-export an object at all, and use named exports instead so that you can import them separately or on a namespace object:

```
// request.js
export default function send() {
  … send() …
}
```

```
// main.js
import * as request from './request'
…
request.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

well just as a quick glimpse, I would say that you should

```
 console.log(this)
```

to see the value of it in the first and second request.
I didn't build your code to check it, but I assume it is an issue with your context.

Still not sure what you try to achieve, but you can always use

```
 someFunction.bind(this)
```

again it is quite vague but maybe it will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is simple solution.

```
//request.js
export function send () {
  ... do stuff ...
    send(); // Can't call "send" of undefined
}

//main.js
import {send} from './request'

export default class Main extends Component {
  init() {
    send();
  }
}
```